# ERRO "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object"

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle

Quando tento rodar esta parte do meu código no Oracle Live SQL, dá o erro de "nome já atribuído a objeto existente". Porém não tem nomes repetidos aqui, a não ser minhas chaves primárias e estrangeiras. Alguém consegue me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

```
CREATE TABLE TB_PROVA (
ID_PROVA INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
DT_PROVA DATE,
NM_SITUACAO VARCHAR(255),
ID_CIRCUITO INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT FK_CIPR FOREIGN KEY (ID_CIRCUITO) REFERENCES TB_CIRCUITO (ID_CIRCUITO) );
```

Comment: confira novamente, se a mensagem diz que já tem um objeto deve haver, pode ser a tabela "TB_PROVA" ou a FK "FK_CIPR", experimente mudar os nomes para confirmar

Comment: Select * from dba_objects ...

Comment: Mesmo que eu rode apenas essa parte do código (essa única tabela) ele dá esse erro. Como se dentro dessa tabela eu tivesse 2 objetos com nomes iguais.

Comment: Tente assim e fale se funcionou: `CREATE TABLE TB_PROVA_NOVA (
ID_PROVA INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
DT_PROVA DATE,
NM_SITUACAO VARCHAR(255),
ID_CIRCUITO INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT FK_CIPR_2 FOREIGN KEY (ID_CIRCUITO) REFERENCES TB_CIRCUITO (ID_CIRCUITO) );`

Answer (score 1):

> Alguém consegue me ajudar a encontrar o erro?

O erro é que já existe uma tabela com esse nome **`TB_PROVA`** .

Execute para verificar se a tabela já existe:

```
Select * from TB_PROVA;
```

Para recriar uma tabela, você precisa excluir a tabela já existente.

Quando já existe uma tabela com o mesmo nome, o erro é:

```
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
```

Quando já existe uma `constraint` o erro será:

```
ORA-02264: name already used by an existing constraint
```

Caso o erro fosse de coluna já existente, o erro exibido seria:

```
ORA-00957: duplicate column name
```

**Excluir tabela**
Caso deseje excluir a tabela já existente com intenção de recriá-la:

```
DROP TABLE TB_PROVA
```

Pode ver a simulação feita no Fiddle, acesse: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8f5b9/2